# Are the gramatical cases slowly disappearing in Romanian or they were never that used in the common speech?

Tags: historical-linguistics, comparative-linguistics, romanian

Where I live in Muntenia, people rarely use the dative anymore and replace it with the preposition “la” + the nominative/accusative form of the noun or pronoun. “Am dat la băiat să mănânce” instead of “am dat băiatului să mănânce”. It most often happens with pronouns: “a dat la altcineva” instead of “a dat altcuiva”.
I have also heard the genitive being replaced with the preposition “de” + the nominative/accusative form of the noun or pronoun. “Elicopterul zbura in jur de București” instead of “elicopterul zbura in jurul Bucureștiului”. Most often it is replaced with “la” + noun/pronoun or with “lui” + noun/pronoun ( usage that is correct in standard Romanian only with personal names.

Excuse my ignorance of grammatical cases and me probably completely getting them wrong. This wasn’t an attempt of answering my own question or even describing this phenomenon exhaustively from more than a personal view, I merely tried to make myself understood.

Is this analytical tendency as old as Romanian is and it somehow survived together with the synthetic tendency, is it more common in certain dialects or is it very recent? Is it class/sociocultural background dependent? Can it be traced? What is some good literature that deals with it?

Comment: Similar in German, by the way.

Comment: It's not so surprising, given: 1) A Romanian word's stress is hardly ever on the case marker 2) at least one neighbouring language appears to be doing the same, Bulgarian

Answer (score -2):

The dative case does not really disappear, it is just there are too many people with sub-par education (regardless of them being officially uneducated, or actually even having a diploma). People with good education actually use the dative case as norm. Educated people actually make fun of each other when one of them talks before connecting the tongue to the brain. I know because I was part of groups of these kids of people.

What is more surprising is that there are people which use the correct genitive / dative even with names.

> I-am dat lu' Gina o carte.

vs.

> I-am dat Ginei o carte.

So while it is sad that statistically the educated people are fewer, they still exist, and they will continue to exist. And that is why the dative will continue to exist.

---

> or they were never that used in the common speech?

Oh, they were used in common speech a lot, and they still are. But, as I said, they require at least some minimal education on the side of the speaker.

Comment: the situation you've described is exactly what you'd expect if the dative was disappearing in speech. The more educated people may remain attached to the traditional grammar used in formal writing, and so describe those speaking varieties that have lost it as having substandard grammar, when in reality they're both just describing different varieties of the same language